# Why $(nkn^{-1})k^{-1}=n(kn^{-1}k^{-1})\in N\cap K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I'm reading Hungerford's Algebra and trying to understand the proof of $(iv)$:

> [image]

I'm a bit confused, in the end of the proof, why $(nkn^{-1})k^{-1}=n(kn^{-1}k^{-1})\in N\cap K$? I understand this looks like the condition for normality but it's shifted in a weird way.

Comment: Note that $N$ and $K$ are subgroups in particular, so they are closed under products. By normality of $K$, the first expression is a product of elements of $K$ and thus is in $K$, and by normality of $N$, the second expression is a product of elements in $N$ and thus is in $N$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(nkn^{−1})k^{−1}$ lies in $K$ since $K$ is normal, and

$n(kn^{−1}k^{−1})$ lies in $N$ since $N$ is normal.

Since both expressions are the same, they lie in the intersection $N\cap K$.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused, there is an extra $k^{-1}$ in the first expression and an extra $n$ in the second expression. We know that the expression in parenthesis is in $K$ and $N$ respectively. Why will they still be in $K$ and $N$ when we "add" that extra letters?

Comment: Subgroups are closed under multiplication and taking inverse elements.